# how to display names in alphabetical groups in Handlebarsjs underscorejs

Tags: underscore.js, handlebars.js

Hi am New to Handlebarsjs.

I have a collection of contacts with name, email, phone, etc. as below

```
[
  {
    "name": "Bob Wolmer",
    "email": "bob@wolmer.com",
    "phone": "(535) 235-1234",
    "address": "301 Cobblestone Wy., Berdrock 00000",
    "contactId": "1121",
    "labels": {}
  },
  {
    "name": "Wilma Erra",
    "email": "wilma@erra.com",
    "phone": "(535) 235-3659",
    "address": "301 Cobblestone Wy., Berdrock 70777",
    "contactId": "1122",
    "labels": {}
  },
  {
    "name": "Brad",
    "email": "brad@brad.com",
    "phone": "(535) 235-3546",
    "address": "301 Cobblestone Wy., Redrock 70777",
    "contactId": "1123",
    "labels": [{"name": "Friends"},{"name": "Family"}]
  },
  {
    "name": "",
    "email": "wilson@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(535) 235-3657",
    "address": "301 Cobblestone Wy., Dedrock 70777",
    "contactId": "1124",
    "labels": [{"name": "Friends"}]
  }
]
```

I want to display the names as below

```
B
Bob
Brad

W
Wilma Erra
```

Can any one suggest me how to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thanks for your time @dcarson, is there a way so that this functionality could be performed on the collections object.
Although the sortBy is not working for but I have used comparator to sort the collection as in below

`this.collection.comparator = function(item) {
       return [item.get("email"), item.get("name")];
     };
     
     this.collection.sort();`

Comment: Do you mean perform this functionality on a Backbone collection?

Answer (score 10):

Lets just say that you have assigned that JSON to a variable named `contacts` You can use underscore to group by the first letter of the name property like so:

```
var groupedContacts = _.groupBy(contacts, function(contact){ 
    return contact.name.substr(0,1); 
});
```

You could then iterate through your groups, maybe sort them and write the content as per your example like this:

```
_.each(groupedContacts, function (contacts, key) {

    console.log(key); // writes the Index letter

    // optional sort
    var sortedContacts = _.sortBy(contacts, function (contact) {
         return contact.name;
     });

     _.each(sortedContacts, function(contact) {
         // Writes the contact name
         console.log(contact.name); 
     });
});
```

So in a real world application, you would want to replace the `console.log` lines with Handlebars templates and/or put it in a helper (however be wary of embedding HTML string in JavaScript as a rule), but thats the easy bit. Also, you may wish sort your `groupedContacts` to get the index in order too. You can do this using the same `sortBy` method shown in my example above.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define the Handlebars Template that suits your JSON layout;

```
{{#list people}}{{name}} {{email}} {{phone}} {{address}} {{contactId}} {{labels}}{{/list}}
```

I assume people is the name of your JSON list like this;

```
{ people: [
  {
    "name": "Bob Wolmer",
    "email": "bob@wolmer.com",
    "phone": "(535) 235-1234",
    "address": "301 Cobblestone Wy., Berdrock 00000",
    "contactId": "1121",
    "labels": {}
  },
  {
    "name": "Wilma Erra",
    "email": "wilma@erra.com",
    "phone": "(535) 235-3659",
    "address": "301 Cobblestone Wy., Berdrock 70777",
    "contactId": "1122",
    "labels": {}
  },
  {
    "name": "Brad",
    "email": "brad@brad.com",
    "phone": "(535) 235-3546",
    "address": "301 Cobblestone Wy., Redrock 70777",
    "contactId": "1123",
    "labels": [{"name": "Friends"},{"name": "Family"}]
  },
  {
    "name": "",
    "email": "wilson@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(535) 235-3657",
    "address": "301 Cobblestone Wy., Dedrock 70777",
    "contactId": "1124",
    "labels": [{"name": "Friends"}]
  }
]}
```

Then you can register your `list` Handlebars template using like this and iterate through your JSON;

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('list', function(items, options) {
  var out = "<ul>";
  var names = [];
  var letters = [];
  for(var i=0, l=items.length; i<l; i++) {
    name = items[i].name;
    if(name == ""){
        continue;
    }
    var firstLetter = name.substring(0,1);
    var arrayWithFirstLetter = names[firstLetter];
    if(arrayWithFirstLetter == null){
       names[firstLetter] = [];
       letters.push(firstLetter);
    }
    var firstName = name.indexOf(" ") == -1 ? name : name.substring(0,name.indexOf(" "));
    names[firstLetter].push(firstName)
  }

  for(var i=0; i < letters.length; i++) {
     out = out + "<li>" + letters[i] + "</li>";
     for(var k=0; k < names[letters[i]].length; k++){
       out = out + "<li>" + names[letters[i]][k] + "</li>";
     }
  }

  return out + "</ul>";
});
```

The output is;

- B
- Bob
- Brad
- W
- Wilma