# trouble having sorting an array with underscore.js

Tags: javascript

**Im trying to sort the following list. But i get this:**

B 
Buller 
Bøller

A
Agnes

C
Cara

**And I would like this:**

A
Agnes

B
Buller
Bøller

C
Cara

I have see it here:
[how to display names in alphabetical groups in Handlebarsjs underscorejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615938/how-to-display-names-in-alphabetical-groups-in-handlebarsjs-underscorejs)

Any help would be very nice ....

```
var series =
    [
        { slug: "et", title: "Buller" },
         { slug: "fem", title: "Bøller" },
        { slug: "to", title: "Agnes" },
        { slug: "tre", title: "Cara" }
    ];  




   function sortByName (array){
    return _.sortBy(array, "title");
}





groupedContacts = _.groupBy(series, function(contact){ 
    return contact.title.substr(0,1); 
}); 


   _.each(groupedContacts, function (series, key) {



    console.log(key); // writes the Index letter

    // optional sort

 var sortedContacts = _.sortBy(series, function (contact) {
         return contact.title;
     });


     _.each(sortedContacts, function(contact) {
         // Writes the contact name
         console.log(contact.title); 

     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to do grouping if you want to do sorting. Remove the following code

```
groupedContacts = _.groupBy(series, function(contact){ 
    return contact.title.substr(0,1); 
}); 


_.each(groupedContacts, function (series, key) {


    console.log(key); // writes the Index letter

    // optional sort

    var sortedContacts = _.sortBy(series, function (contact) {
         return contact.title;
    });


    _.each(sortedContacts, function(contact) {
        // Writes the contact name
        console.log(contact.title); 

    });
});
```

and just use `sortBy`.

```js
var series = [
    { slug: "et", title: "Buller" },
    { slug: "fem", title: "Bøller" },
    { slug: "to", title: "Agnes" },
    { slug: "tre", title: "Cara" }
];

var sorted = _.sortBy(series, 'title');

document.getElementById('sorted').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>


<div id="sorted"></div>
```